# file.choose in r open the dialog box as pop behind and not pop up

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application with an action button to update the data.  Upon clicking the button, I am using the following code to choose and read a csv file.

```
updatebi <- function(x){

    y <- function(...) {
        pathname <- NULL;
        tryCatch({
            pathname <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE);

'dosomething'

df <- x 
mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "root", password = "abba1221", dbname = "dbdb", host = "localhost")
dbWriteTable(mydb, name = "byname", value = df, overwrite = FALSE, append = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
.rs.restartR()
}, error = function(ex) {
})
pathname;
    }
x <- y()
}
```

I tried using this code in both windows and OS X. The file choose dialog opens but always hides behind other windows that are already open.

How do I use file.choose() so that the file choose dialog always appears in the front.

Comment: I know this is a pretty old thread, I am having the same problem 7-1/2 years afterwards.  I see the rJava solution below, but did anyone figure this out ?  To me it is happening with Rstudio, I thought it was something to do with its interaction with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution for the same problem. I tried this one:

```
library(rJava)
library(rChoiceDialogs)
jchoose.files()
```

I gave it a shot and ran jchoose.files() 20 or 30 times, canceling or choosing a file each time, and the selector always popped up. Not once was it hidden. Still not 100% sure, but looks promising.

I also tried the solution below, but the file chooser didn't pop up some of the times.

```
library(tcltk)
tk_choose.files()
```